# Why does for loop actually return a value as a return instruction?

Tags: c, for-loop, return

This (a() I mean) returns a random number with a function defined as :

```
int a (void) {
    for (int e = 0; e < 10; e++);
}
```

And this is a factorial function I've created, but no idea why it is returning a value (and it works !) :

```
long int factorial (int n) {
    for (long int s = 1; s *= n, --n;);
}
```

Is it some C weird feature ?
And what's the rule to know what it will return ?

Comment: Turn compiler warnings on and lo and behold...the compiler complains!

Comment: The rule is on Intel: the `eax` register generally holds the int return value. So the value that was put there is what the caller assumes is returned. since you don't know what the compiler generated for code, you can't know what the compiler put in eax and you have _Accidental Correct Bahavor_, a subset of _Undefined Behavior_.

Comment: This is undefined behavior according to the standard, so there are no rules you could follow to determine what the posted code does.